# display, adjust, & combine 2 images with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, image-manipulation

I want to create an application where it can display two images, first image is a face image from user and the second is the nose image that is available to choose to be matched with the face. So when i upload face images, i can choose the matching nose and adjust position, size etc.. then merge them into one image. I want to create with JavaScript and maybe merge them into one using php function, I still confuse where should I start.

Any idea? reference? Thank all

Answer (score 0):

A tutorial for Overlapping Images in php using GD:

[Overlapping Images with GD (part 1)](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Overlapping-Images-with-GD/)

[Overlapping Images with GD (part 2)](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Overlapping-Images-with-GD/1/)

[Overlapping Images with GD (part 3)](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Overlapping-Images-with-GD/2/)

other functions to upload images and showing them and handling some user user friendly actions can be done easily with javascript. if there was any question in these parts, I can help.